# remove duplicate element from array in java got java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException

Tags: java, arrays

I am trying to remove duplicate element from int[] array in java. After declaring a tempArray at the result I am getting

> java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int[] givenArray = {1,1,2,2,3,3,4,4,5,5,6,4,4,3,3,2,2,7,7,6,5,4,3,8,9,6};
    int n = givenArray.length;

    Arrays.sort( givenArray );

    int j = 0;
    int[] tempArray = {};
    for (int i = 0; i < n-1; i++) {
        if (givenArray[i] != givenArray[i+1]) {
           tempArray[j] = givenArray[i];
           j++;
        }
    }

    tempArray[j] = givenArray[n-1];

    for (int i : tempArray) {
        System.out.print(i+" ");
    }
}
```

Comment: you should add some code lines, cause otherwise its imposible to say anything esse than: you are trying to use a position of the array that does not exist

Comment: How are you expecting to put something in an array with 0 length?   `int[] tempArray = {};`

Comment: You could instead use Set to achieve this. As you are just printing and there is no compulsion to return the result as an array, you can just print all the values present in the set

Comment: if I put int[] tempArray = new int[n]; Then the result came 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0; Remaining index are getting 0.

Comment: @Muhammad well obviously you need to keep track of how many distinct items you actually put.

Comment: Yes, an array has a fixed size, so if you remove the duplicates from an array, it has more elements than the unique ones you have left.

Comment: Thanks you all. :) I have got one answer from the link jbx shared.

Answer (score 1):

Your logic is pretty much alright Muhammad. Just 2 changes need to be made. I have listed them below:

1. As Würgspaß has pointed out,  you need to declare and instantiate the array `temparray[]` like this: `int[] tempArray = new int[n];` With the way you have defined, it creates an empty array with size 0. And as a characteristic of an array, an array's size cannot be changed. Hence it gives you an OutOfBounds exception when you try to insert into it.
2. Access the `tempArray[]` in the `for` loop using the usual iterative way, with the `i` value ranging from `0` to `j`(`j` inclusive).  ==>

   ```
   for (int i = 0; i <= j; i++)
   {
       System.out.print(tempArray[i] + " ");
   }
   ```

Here is the overall **updated code:**

```
package removeduplicatesfromarray;

import java.util.Arrays;

public class Main {

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    int[] givenArray = {1,1,2,2,3,3,4,4,5,5,6,4,4,3,3,2,2,7,7,6,5,4,3,8,9,6};
    int n = givenArray.length;

    Arrays.sort( givenArray );

    int j = 0;
    int[] tempArray = new int[givenArray.length];
    for (int i = 0; i < n-1; i++)
    {
        if (givenArray[i] != givenArray[i+1])
        {
           tempArray[j] = givenArray[i];
           j++;
        }
    }
    tempArray[j] = givenArray[n-1];

    for (int i = 0; i <= j; i++)
    {
        System.out.print(tempArray[i] + " ");
    }

  }
}
```

**OUTPUT**:

> `1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9`

Answer (score -1):

`int[] tempArray = {};` defines an empty array with 0 length. Use `int[] tempArray = new int[n];`
to avoid `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException`.

Comment: wonder why the downvote here is for? it's a very valid point highlighted in the answer.